# Swift IOS view opacity issue

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view that has an alpha value of 0.7, and contains an image view. However, I don't want the image view to be transparent. What should I do so that the superview is transparent but the image view is not?

Answer (score 2):

A superview's `alpha` *does* affect its subviews, so there is no way to do what you're describing if you're going to change the superview's `alpha`. If the superview's `alpha` is 0.7, and the image view is its subview, that the image view's *effective* alpha can *never* be *more* than 0.7.

So you would need to take a completely different approach.

You could, for example, change the transparency of the superview's `backgroundColor`. That would not affect the image view which is its subview.

Or, *don't* make the image view the superview's subview; put it in front but not as a subview.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Sorry about the duplicate.